# Definition of stage of LLL; Removing integer linear dependency with LLL

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

In the BKZ algorithm presented in the image below, I don't understand what it is supposed to mean LLL($*$,$\mu$) at stage $j$.

Take for example line 6.

We insert the new vector into the described position, and then we do what?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to refer to the [Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovász lattice basis reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) .

---

For example in line 6, the basis $({\bf b}_1,\ldots,{\bf b}_n)$ is already LLL-reduced, either by line 1 or by an earlier visit to lines 6 or 8. Hence the basis
$$({\bf b}_1,\ldots,\textstyle\sum_{i=j}^kv_i{\bf b}_i,{\bf b}_j,\ldots,{\bf b}_h),$$
to which you're applying the LLL-algorithm in line 6, already has its first $j-1$ vectors LLL-reduced. So you can skip the first $j-1$ stages of the LLL-algorithm, and start at stage $j$.

Comment: Don't you say xD Now without kidding, what I do not understand is what does LLL when we refer to a stage

Comment: What part of the description of the algorithm given in the link is unclear to you?

Comment: I am familiar with the LLL algorithm, but I don't know what is the meaning of LLL-reducing a basis at a certain stage.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see, I suspected that, but I have I question about this. As you may know, LLL is composed by a reduction step and a swap step. If the swap step occurs then we have to go to the start of LLL which is the reduction step. If this happens, we have to do the reduction step for all stages, right? I mean, this skip of stages only applies for the beginning of LLL right?

Comment: That's right. I suspect this won't happen because of the setup of this algorithm, though I'm not entirely sure of this.

Comment: Therefore I don't see the need of saying the stage stuff. Maybe it's for efficiency reasons